# Battery Profiling Device

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I am working on building a battery pack for a solar car. I need to know if there is a device on the market that will "profile" the batteries (lifepo4) that I have, so that I can put like batteries together in a pack.

What would a device like this be called?

Just as a note, I am not looking for sales links, or which is the best, but I just want to know what to search for.

Comment: Are you just wanting to monitor the voltage/current/temp? Or do you want State of Charge, cycling count, Depth of Discharge, etc? Do you need to interact with the batteries (i.e. cell balancing)? Also are you looking to log data or just have a 'live reading'? And lastly do you need a display on-board or can you wait and connect it to a PC to download your data later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These devices are called *battery analyzers*.  
[Here's one made by West Mountain Radio .](http://www.westmountainradio.com/cba.php)  Don't know if these are big enough for a car propulsion battery.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was looking for. For reference, I am testing each cell individually, so each cell is only 3.6V.

Comment: I bought it, and it works flawlessly.